# selectTextOnFocus not working for autofilled data

Tags: react-native, textfield

I have few `TextField` inputs. At the beginning only one input is enabled for entering data. Once data is entered and enter button is pressed API call is triggered and response data is received. This data autofills remaining `TextField`.

My issue appears after autofill happens - `selectTextOnFocus` can no longer select text which is autofilled. It selects it for a second and removes selection.

Any ideas what could be the issue?

```
return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
...
       <TextField label={'EAN'}
                  value={ean}
                  onChangeText={(value) => formStateChange(ean, value)}
                  ref={(input) => {
                     this.eanInputField = input
                  }}
                  onSubmitEditing={() => this.handleInput('ean')}

        />
...
        <TextField label={'Actual price'}
                   value={actualPrice}
                   editable={editableField}
                   selectTextOnFocus
        /> 
      </View>
)
```

My expected result is that `selectTextOnFocus` could select whole input text after data is autoFilled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found solution to my issue - I have added `multiline` property to `<TextField`,
Now field input data is selected as expected (select all).